# How to display the taxonomy menu block when content display?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I created a vocabulary

```
Vocabulary 1
- Term 1.1
-- Term 1.1.1 (url : autogenerate)
-- Term 1.1.2 (url : autogenerate)
```

And I created a taxonomy menu block, a content type and a view by taxonomy->term. everything is so far so good.

But when I click content, I don't know how to display the taxonomy menu block when the content is displaying.

I tried to select content type at taxonomy's menu block. But not working.